# Ionic 2 - How to use event binding in index.html

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, event-binding

I want to use event binding in index.html.

I need to make favicon and dynamic shortcut icons from database urls (Firebase);

It would look something like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type= "image/x-icon" href="{{icon.url}}">
```

But I do not know how to use variables in the index.html file.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Hey Matheus, you can not do that (binding) as index.html is not part of Angular magic. If you need to introduce dynamic links for your icons etc - it is best to use plain javascript (you can also inline it inside of index.html)

Comment: As @SergeyRudenko mentioned, this cannot be done. Angular's scope begins inside the root tag, which in the case of Ionic is the `<ion-app>` tag inside your `index.html`. You cannot use Angular's functionality outside the root tag, which means you cannot use it in `index.html`.